# Combine a str to a list in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this which top 3 rows look like this:
`df.head()`

```
                Category    Key_words
     Title      
- 14 Nyhederne  kortfilm    (direkte, fyringer)
- 6 Nyhederne   kortfilm    (med, af)
- 6 Nyhederne   nyheder     (med, nã)
```

The `Category` is a string, and I would like to append that word inside the list of `Key_words`. I have tried append, combine, etc etc but I cant make it workl...

I want to create a new column `bag_of_words` for my output, like this:

```
                Category    Key_words            bag_of_words
     Title      
- 14 Nyhederne  kortfilm    (direkte, fyringer)  (kortfilm, direkte, 
                                                  fyringer)
- 6 Nyhederne   kortfilm    (med, af)            (kortfilm, med, af)
- 6 Nyhederne   nyheder     (med, nã)            (nyheder, med, nã)
```

I tried `df.Key_words.join([df.Category])` but I get:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: Are the values in your `Key_words` column type `list`?

Comment: yes, `key_words` is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are tuples in `Key_words` columns:

```
df['bag_of_words'] = [(a,) + b for a, b in zip(df['Category'], df['Key_words'])]
```

If values are lists in `Key_words` column:

```
df['bag_of_words'] = [[a] + b for a, b in zip(df['Category'], df['Key_words'])]
print (df)
            Title  Category            Key_words  \
0  - 14 Nyhederne  kortfilm  [direkte, fyringer]   
1   - 6 Nyhederne  kortfilm            [med, af]   
2   - 6 Nyhederne   nyheder            [med, ns]   

                    bag_of_words  
0  [kortfilm, direkte, fyringer]  
1            [kortfilm, med, af]  
2             [nyheder, med, ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply jezrael.
It seems that the `key_words` is a list, and the code you gave me gives me this error:



TypeError: must be str, not list`

Comment: @AlexS - changed solution

Comment: Yes! It works now, thank you so much for you fast reply. 

I am mostly working with R, but now I have this Python assignment in uni.

It seems that you have a lot of experience jezrael, could you recommend me a few Python courses for me to start learning the language? Thank you in advance

Comment: By the way, I need to wait 6 more mins to accept your answer

Comment: @AlexS - You can check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) tutorials.

Comment: @AlexS - oops, just realised first solution  should be simplify, so edit answer.

Comment: I now want to make a count matrix, in order to compute the cosine similarity between movies according to the `bag_of_words`

`# instantiating and generating the count matrix
count = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df['bag_of_words'])`

gives me this error:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: Thanks again sir.

I tried:
`# instantiating and generating the count matrix
count = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(list(zip(*df.bag_of_words))[0])`

but

`ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192352/discussion-between-jezrael-and-alex-s).